# Can I use Xcode to get the llvm IR?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a project which contains both Objective-C and Swift. I want to get the LLVM IR by using Xcode, is there anyway to do that?
I try to put `-emit-ir` into "Other Swift flag", but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the correct flag is `-emit-llvm` https://github.com/stanislaw/LLVM-Cheatsheet/blob/master/README.md#generate-human-readable-llvm-ir-from-a-file= You'd then have to check the build log, because that's where it would probably end up being dumped.

Comment: `-emit-llvm` is the flag for `clang`, and I think the correct flag for `Swiftc` is `-emit-ir`.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
You need to  put `-Xfrontend -emit-ir` into  `Other Swift Flags`, and the `LLVM IR` is in the `.o` file!